# Google map clickable

Tags: visualforce, google-apps

I have a visualforce page where I could able to show all account in google map.

My requierment is when I clcik on single account marker, I would like to go to detail page of the account.

Here is the code snippet Where I got all markers in addressinstances.

```
for(var i = 0; i < addrInstances.length; i++)
                        {
                            var currLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(addrInstances[i].Location__Latitude__s,addrInstances[i].Location__Longitude__s )
                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: currLatLng,
                            map: map,
                            title:addrInstances[i].Name+ '\n'  +addrInstances[i].BillingStreet + '\n'  +addrInstances[i].BillingCity + '\n'  +addrInstances[i].BillingState  
                            });
                        /* google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

                               window.location ='https://na15.salesforce.com/addrInstances[i].id';
                               alert(addresses[i].name);
                            });
                            */
                            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() 
                            {
                                window.location = '/' + addrInstances[i].id;
                            });

                    } */
```

Just wondering What I am doing wrong. Please guide me so that I can click on marker to navigate to detail page

Thanks in advance

Please help in this regard.

Thanks

Comment: Could you include what you have at the moment? Visualforce page and Extension perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

Just create a new `click` listener for the marker (assuming you know the account ID):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
    window.location = '/' + accountId;
});
```